# how to save input id +text color in cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

[Here](http://jsbin.com/viraqixicigi/1/), I am saving input in cookies.

When I re-open it will show all the data I enter. My question is when I enter wrong data, the input turns red, but when I close and reopen the file the wrong input is not red.

Can any one help?

Thank you.

```
//save as cookies
var formsave1=new autosaveform({
    formid: 'save',
    pause: 1000 //<--no comma following last option!
})
```

Comment: You don't need to save the color... You just have to check for wrong data when you load from cookie...

Comment: any code help please i tried but not happening @LcSalazar thank you

Comment: @swaroopk if you don't know how to use that library. You can achieve your goal by simple javaScript.

Comment: Thank you for reply @xK0nB1n . I have tried in many ways. if you can please help me.

Comment: @swaroopk I can't do it with the library you imported because for that I have to study the whole of it. But the same thing you wrote in the question can be done by simple javaScript.